# About a Feynman diagram of the fourth-order for the Compton scattering

Tags: scattering, feynman-diagrams

I have been able to draw 16 of them.  But I was not able to find the last one. It is told in the problem that there are 17 of them. So I had to check the solution and I find this diagram;

[image: 17e fourth -order]

At the same time, can someone tell me how to calculate the number of possible diagrams relative to the number of vertices?  For the moment, I don't know what to write as a formula in each vertex, that will come later.  But an explication would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Mario

Comment: The lower two vertices look wrong; did you mean to put a photon line there?

Comment: No. This image comes from Griffiths 2008 (Introduction to elementary particles, solutions manual page 10).  That is why I am confused about this one. The convention is that time goes in the «x» positive axis direction.

Comment: That is almost certainly a mistake, the line should be a photon line. There is no three electron vertex.

Comment: This image comes from the book itself.  Maybe someone with a more recent edition ( >2008) of the solution could confirm that the diagram is still there.  I don't know what to say more. Sorry!